# Is there evidence that Jesus was a Dalai Lama?

Tags: comparative-christianity, buddhism, magi

The stories of the wise men from the East giving gifts to the baby Jesus seem remarkably similar to the way a new Dalai Lama is found. For example...

Magi, or astrologers, look in the stars to guess who would be the next reincarnation of Buddha. Perhaps some astrologers from Tibet, or somewhere, read the stars and deduced that the next Dalai Lama would be born in Bethlehem. So, "following the stars", they set out on their camels to where they predict the baby was and they found Jesus in a stable. They offered gifts (which were the possessions of the previous Dali Lama) to see if the baby would recognize them.

Then they took the baby back to Tibet, where Jesus trained as the Dalai Lama until he was 30. Whereby perhaps for some reason he had to leave so he went back to Nazareth. There he began to preach what he learned. His stories inspired by Buddhist teachings. "Do unto others..." etc.

Then the Jews said "You must be the new Messiah" as foretold. And Jesus said, "Well you said that, not me."

Well there it kind of breaks down because Jesus was teaching about the Kingdom of Heaven and not reincarnation or enlightenment.

Is this a common belief that Jesus could have been chosen as a Dalai Lama type person by Eastern astrologers?

Comment: Jesus's whole message of eternal life with God is completely antithetical to Buddhist teaching.

Comment: Again, while I think the answer to this question is pretty clear, I don't understand all the downvotes. This guy asks if there is any evidence, and the answer very clearly explains why there is not good evidence. Lots of people have theories like this, which are rooted in shallow understandings of history, and Christianity in general. Instead of downvoting them to oblivion, we should applaud the opportunity to answer them clearly for future inquirers.

Comment: @curiousdannii How? The Jews did not believe in eternal life. But budhism does. In the sense of eternal reincarnation. Thus when Jesus says, if you follow my way you will have eternal life, he could well have been talking about Budhism. Thus Christianity is closer in this sense to Budhism than Judaism. The Budhists believed they could enter Nirvana. Change "Nivarna" for "Heaven" and it's very close indeed.

Comment: @zooby Nirvana is ceasing to be. Love is the problem in Buddhism, not the goal. Etc etc.

Comment: Well Nirvana is "free from surffering". Like Heaven in a way. My point being that Jesus may have been teaching budhist teachings, but got misinterpreted by later deciples. Or he may have misinterpreted them himself, or emelished them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

From Wikipedia:

> Dalai Lama (UK: /ˈdælaɪ ˈlɑːmə/, US: /ˈdɑːlaɪ ˈlɑːmə/;[1][2] Standard Tibetan: ཏཱ་ལའི་བླ་མ་, Tā la'i bla ma, [táːlɛː láma]) is a title given by the Tibetan people for the foremost spiritual leader of the Gelug or "Yellow Hat" school of Tibetan Buddhism, the newest of the classical schools of Tibetan Buddhism.

Reading further shows that the first Dalai Lama lived from 1391-1474, and wasn't even named the Dalai Lama until 1578.

The concept of the Dalai Lama seems to have only been around for the last millennium. Furthermore, Tibetan Buddhism was not formally established until the 7th-9th century. Since this is well documented, and there isn't a historical dispute for the time of Jesus' life, there is no evidence that Jesus was a Dalai Lama.

If this isn't a satisfactory answer, one could also write a lengthy answer about how different Buddhism is from the teachings of Jesus. Or start here [Did the teachings of Buddha influence Jesus?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15050/did-the-teachings-of-buddha-influence-jesus?rq=1)